# Django: reusable app testing

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, tdd, pip

By following official [**Django doc**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/reusable-apps/), I've extracted an app from my project and made it reusable and installable using `pip` (currently I still have to learn how to release it on pypi but that's another story)... so far so good... but now I have no idea how to run the tests I wrote for my app, since after installing it in my project using pip **Django** stopped to execute those tests (by default in **Django 1.7** only project-apps tests are picked up)... so my question is: how can I run tests for my apps now that it has been extracted from the main project sources?

ps: of course I don't want to force the potential users of my app to run the tests I wrote, but I have to run them while working on the app on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm an idiot... the only thing I have to do is passing the app name in the test command:

```
python manage.py test -v 2 -p "Test*.py" --noinput --settings=settings.test my_app
```